# TargetSdkVersion in library grater then targetSdkVersion in application

Tags: android

I have an Android application with targetSdkVersion = 26 and compileSdkVersion = 26. Is it possible to work fine when I use a library (use gradle dependencies) with target targetSdkVersion = 28 and compileSdkVersion = 28 ? Or it is requre to update target and compile versions in application like in library? Is target and compile versions should be the same? Is target and compile version should be 28 to migrate to AndroidX? Is AndroidX can be use with version 26?

Answer (score 0):

Target SDK version:
The targetSdkVersion value tells Android which API level your app was designed to run on. Keep this to the latest version.

Compile SDK:
version, or build target, specifies which version to use when building your own code. When Android
Studio is looking to find the classes and methods you refer to in your imports, the build target
determines which SDK version it checks against.

You should update the target and compile sdk to 28 in order to use the new library